# How do I call Junit test (Rest call) cases after deploy war in tomcat through Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit

I am doing continues deployment of my Project war through Maven(Build tool), jenkins(CD tool) and  SVN as version control.
I am able deploy war to tomcat , now i want to run some junit which call's Rest web services to that deployed jar, how would jenkins do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via "**execute shell**" in jenkins. Firstly, you can check whether  "execute shell" is been installed in your jenkins or not it comes as a add-on. If you have shell, you can write a small piece of code to execute your code. Remember this code will be executed on the jenkins slave box which has used to deploy your war.

**Start jar file : java -jar .jar**

2 ways to do that :

A) **mvn exec:exec -Dexec.args="arg1"** (this needs maven to be installed on the jenkins box), call you test case directly. Remember before running you should be in directory path.

For example :

1. **cd ${HOME}/(code directory** which you want to navigate to in order to run command) - Here HOME is /home/jenkinsUser
2. Now you are the location(although the first step is optional, you can run without navigating to the location), from where you want to run your unit test case. You can run them as a java command from there, passing the parameter to the deployed jar.